# Wait until DLL is finished

Tags: vb.net, dll, backgroundworker

Problem :

I have a VB.NET DLL that displays a form.  A separate program will call on that DLL.

Form.dll opens, and displays options.  String is returned, based on  options are selected.

Question :

1. How to make calling program wait until string is returned.
2. If form.dll minimized or closed, need to return CANCELLED, to release calling program.

Do I open DLL on a backgroundworker thread?

Answer (score 0):

1. Call `ShowDialog()`, which will only return once the form is closed.
2. Handle the appropriate events and return `null`.